# condition failing if stament php

Tags: magento, php

I have the following code:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getColumns() as $_column): ?> 
    <?php if( $_column->getHeaderHtml() == "Kit"): ?>
        <p>Yes im a kit</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <th<?php echo $_column->getHeaderHtmlProperty() ?>><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_column->getHeaderHtml() ?></span></th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When i run this code seems getHeaderHtml never is "Kit" however if i Echo out the getHeaderHtml i get "kit" as the first result.  No i cant echo inside an if statements condition.

How do i get this value to a string and compare?

More Info:

Also if i dont echo out getHeadeHtml() and instead save it to a variable and inside a div the div prints out nothing, untill i echo. (suspect thats just the fact you need to iether print or echo a variable to a page)

UPDATE:

been looking at this wrong, the "Kit" that echos out is actually the html.
so its :

```
<a href="#" name="is_kit" title="asc" class="not-sort">
    <span class="sort-title">Kit</span>
</a>
```

So how do i get just the "Kit" value and evaluate it?

Comment: `if ($_column->getHeaderHtml()->__toString() == "Kit")` ?

Comment: __toString() method doesnt exist. just errors the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you already Know what the value should be, you could try using the strrchr.

So in your case.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getColumns() as $_column): ?> 
    <?php if(strrchr($_column->getHeaderHtml(),"Kit")): ?>
        <p>yes im a kit!</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also you may also wish to update your question title as its a little vague.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding (string) before the variable like so: This forces is to be of type String. This is called Type Casting.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getColumns() as $_column): ?> 
    <?php if( (string)$_column->getHeaderHtml() == "Kit"): ?>
        <p>Yes im a kit</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <th<?php echo $_column->getHeaderHtmlProperty() ?>><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_column->getHeaderHtml() ?></span></th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: really odd, because if i echo the method i get "Kit"

Comment: this code is in magento, part of the grid code, i beleive its a varienObject so there isnt any code it just gets a value (i think)